# How can I add NoFollw attributes to all my weebly site external links

Tags: javascript, jquery, weebly

Weebly unfortunately doesn't provide a way to make external links noFollow. I contacted them but to no avail then I looked for this script on the net.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>

<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
        jQuery('a').each(function() {
            // Let's make external links open in a new window.
            var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
            if (typeof href != 'undefined' && href != "" && (href.indexOf('http://') != -1 ||
            href.indexOf('https://') != -1) && href.indexOf(window.location.hostname) == -1) {
                jQuery(this).attr("rel", "nofollow");
            }
        });
    //]]>
</script>
```

However, this code didn't work. 
Can you please tell me what's wrong or help me with a fix. Thank you.

Comment: you can't use JS to adjust markup for machines that don't run JS, fix the html.

Comment: In Weebly, just look at the HTML source code, find the link (should be inside `<a></a>` tags) and add to the `<a>` tag: `rel="nofollow"`.

Comment: Shouldn't your jQuery be placed `$( document ).ready(function(){ //Here });` so that it is only executed when the page is ready?

Answer (score 0):

Weebly supports JavaScript, but has a bit of a different way of doing it than normal web hosts.

First, wrap your code in `$(document).ready`. Then, use the `Custom HTML` element to place the following code in your page:

```
<script type='text/javascript'>
    //<![CDATA[
        $(document).ready(function() {
            jQuery('a').each(function() {
                // Let's make external links open in a new window.
                var href = jQuery(this).attr('href');
                if (typeof href != 'undefined' && href != "" && (href.indexOf('http://') != -1 ||
                href.indexOf('https://') != -1) && href.indexOf(window.location.hostname) == -1) {
                    jQuery(this).attr("rel", "nofollow");
                }
            });
        }
    //]]>
</script>
```

As far as I can tell, Weebly already includes jQuery on the page for you, but if not, then go to `Settings` -> `SEO` and add the jQuery script tag. This will make it show up in your site `<head>` on Weebly.

```
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.3.2/jquery.min.js' type='text/javascript'/>
```

Comment: Unfortunately, nothing worked so far. The code above didn't change anything. The links were still doFollow and even opening external link on external window never took place. I also added the jQuery script tag which messed up the whole site before I removed it. I appreciate your help, but so far weebly platform has been resisting all attempts. I don't know why? but I guess I will keep trying.